# Função SE Aninhada?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Gostaria de saber como aninhar a Função `SE` da seguinte forma:

> `Se G6 for >=20 e <=30 então 100, Se G6 >30 e <=40 então 200, Se G6 >40 e <=50 então 300, Se G6 >50 e <=60 então 400`

Como montar essa função?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você deve usar a fução [`E`](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/E-Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-E-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9) para fazer a união de mais de uma condição. Assim, uma possível resposta para o que você quer é:

> `=SE(E(G6>=20;G6<=30); 100; SE(E(G6>30;G6<=40); 200;
>   SE(E(G6>40;G6<=50); 300; SE(E(G6>50;G6<=60); 400; "VALOR INVÁLIDO"))))`

Note que na última verificação faltou você definir o valor para o SENÃO. Eu coloquei `"VALOR INVÁLIDO"`, mas você deve definir algum valor que faça sentido no seu domínio de problema.

Outra sugestão, mais "facilitada" no sentido de que usa apenas um [`OU`](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-OU-7d17ad14-8700-4281-b308-00b131e22af0) para verificar logo de início se o valor está no intervalo total válido e depois simplesmente verifica limite à limite, foi sugerida pelo colega @Bacco:

> `=SE(OU(G6<20;G6>60); "VALOR INVÁLIDO"; SE(G6>50; 400; SE(G6>40; 300;
>   SE(G6>30; 200; 100))))`

### IMPORTANTE:

Verifique se a sua **real intenção** não seria na verdade fazer algum cálculo sobre o valor. Porque aí você facilita enormemente a sua vida ao evitar esse monte de condições.

Na sua fórmula o único limite inferior inclusivo - isto é, que é verificado com `>=` ao invés de só com `>` - é o 20. Repare:

1. os números **20**, 21, 22, ..., 30 resultam em 100
2. os números 31, 32, ..., 40 resultam em 200
3. os números 41, 42, ..., 50 resultam em 300
4. os números 51, 52, ..., 60 resultam em 400

Supondo que isso esteja errado (e que o 20 não deveria ser incluído no intervalo do 100), você pode obter esse mesmo cálculo multiplicando o dígito da dezena anterior (subtraído de 1 ou por 2, dependendo se é ou não divisível por 10) por 100. A fórmula ficaria assim:

> `=SE(MOD(G6;10)=0; TRUNCAR(G6/10)-2; TRUNCAR(G6/10)-1) * 100`

A primeira parte verifica ([`SE`](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-SE-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)) o resto ([`MOD`](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/MOD-Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-MOD-9b6cd169-b6ee-406a-a97b-edf2a9dc24f3)) da divisão por 10 é 0. Se for, o número é 20, 30, 40, etc. Nesse caso, trata-se do limite superior, então você pega a parte inteira ([`TRUNCAR`](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/TRUNCAR-Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-TRUNCAR-8b86a64c-3127-43db-ba14-aa5ceb292721)) da divisão por 10 e subtrai 2. Caso contrário, pega a parte inteira da divisão por 10 e subtrai só 1. Só então multiplica o valor retornado por 100 para ter o resultado de seu interesse.

Se o 20 fizer mesmo parte do primeiro grupo, aí esse cálculo não funciona. Implementar condições de contorno nele só iria dar mais trabalho, e talvez compense mesmo deixar a regra original com diferentes condições. Eu só estou colocando esse exemplo pra você **refletir** se o seu problema na verdade não é um cálculo ao invés de uma tabela do tipo de-para (que, aliás, também pode ser implementada usando [as funções de busca em tabela](http://blog.luz.vc/excel/como-usar-funcao-procv-vlookup-excel/)).

Comment: Muito Obrigada. Usei a primeira função proposta, e funcionou em parte. Veja bem a minha função: =SE(G2<=117,12;"500,00";SE(E(G2>177,12;G2<=184,4);498;SE(E(G2>184,4;G2<=312,33);350;SE(E(G2>312,33;G2<468);315;"SD")))) dentro dessa função os valores que estão inseridos no segundo teste lógico (G2>117,12;G2<=184,40) está retornando "SD", e deveria retornar "498,00". O que devo fazer?  grata.

Comment: Por nada. Bom, tem alguma coisa errada aí. A sua fórmula tá *muito* estranha: ela compara valores mas deixa intervalos entre eles (tipo 117,12 x 177,12), ela retorna tipos de dados diferentes (ora string, ora número). Além disso, vc não menciona qual é o valor que está em G2. Será que não deveria mesmo retornar `"SD"`? Ou seja, parece falta de atenção da sua parte. Veja a representação gráfica da sua fórmula (é muito útil desenhar assim): http://imgur.com/a/BuZiE O caminho em negrito é o que está sendo feito, se o retorno é `"SD"`. Avalie onde vc cometeu erro.

Comment: OK. Refiz a funçao e deu tudo certo. Muitíssimo obrigada.

Comment: Mais uma vez, por nada. Se a resposta te ajudou, por favor [considere marcá-la como aceita](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Por favor, me permite te perguntar outra coisa, caso minha formula fosse a seguinte: SE H2=100,00 retorne o valor 10,00, SE H2=200,00 retorne o valor 20,00, SE H2= 300,00 retorne o valor 30,00, SE H2=400, retorne o valor 40, senao "SD". Como colocaria essa função?

Comment: Ora, exatamente como você descreve. É só "aninhar" (colocar um dentro do outro) os comandos `SE` lembrando que ele funciona assim: `SE(<condição> ; <valor se condição for verdadeira> ; <valor se condição for falsa>)`. (Se bem que nesse caso você está basicamente dividindo o valor de H2 por 10, não? Ou seja, a sua fórmula mais fácil é simplesmente: `=H2/10`). Ah, este site não é um fórum. Se vc ainda tiver dúvida sobre "como funciona o comando SE do Excel", eu sugiro que abra uma nova pergunta, ok?

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi corretamente, ficará assim.

```
=SE(E(G6>=20;G6<=30);100;SE(E(G6>30;G6<=40);200;SE(E(G6>40;G6<=50);300;SE(E(G6>50;G6<=60);400))))
```

Lembrando que no caso do G6 for inferior a 20 ou superior a 60 o resultado será FALSO.

Comment: Obrigada. Tudo deu certo.